# Where can I find jar dependencies versions for each JBoss release?

Tags: jboss, dependencies, version

I need to easily find what version of, let's say, JGroups bundled with JBoss 4.2.3.

Is there some documentation, wiki, or something else where I can find this information easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/tags/JBoss_4_2_3_GA/build/build-thirdparty.xml

In your specific case, it uses JGroups 2.4.1.SP4. For newer JBoss versions, there's a "component-matrix" directory with a pom.xml with all versions:

https://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/tags/JBoss_5_1_0_GA/component-matrix/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks! Can you please just edit you response changing svn.jboss to anonsvn.jboss, so people don't get the authentication window?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the dependencies for a single JAR file or an application, then you can have a look at [Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) project which helps you also to find missing classes from the classpath, spot if a class/package is located in multiple JAR files and much more. Here you can find also a [Tattletale tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/uncover-jboss-client-jar-list-with-tattletale).
Hope it helps
Francesco